# Manage user balance

Tags: php, sql

I am relatively new, and I am about to make a site, which can store user balance on the site with real money. When they (users) deposit money, all the real money will go straight into a buffer bank account. At same time (when they deposit), each user get some virtual money on the site. When they withdraw, the virtual balance is subtracted the amount they withdraw. And they get transaction back of real money from the buffer bank account depending on how much they withdraw.

The site handles transaction between users and here I follow this guide:
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-mysql-transaction/

About safety right now, I have deposit through SSL and the user password is hashed. Users verify via mail. Users login via _SESSION.

I just want to know, before I deploy and make the website public (in 3-4 months), what should I think about within more safety ? E.g. should user balance, which is sensitive information, be hided somehow? Can someone malicious user e.g. change he/her virtual balance, and withdraw even more than deposit?

Any suggestions/guides/tutorials about safety are very welcome!

Hope to hear from someone, thanks in advance. Have a good day,

Best

Mergh06

Comment: I usually avoid handling money as much as I possibly can. Preferably by using a third party payment provider (ie stripe) that actually know what they're doing. Handling money, credit card information, etc is a complex task, and I'd rather not mess around with it and risk getting something wrong. In your proposed setup it seems a user will have his own virtual account - and share a buffer bank account with all users. A simple sql injection hack to raise his virtual balance would then be pretty catastophic as he could withdraw all the money in the buffer account.

Comment: @JimL Right on the spot! :-)

Comment: Yes, that is what I am afraid of as well. However I need this to function somehow. I use third-party for charging money. But I handle the virtual balance since I guess Stripe not allow me to setup a poll with lottery tickets as I can handle my self. I find that its more eCommerce stuff they can handle ?

Comment: Be aware that running a lottery with real money involved will most probably be restricted by a law in your country, even if it's online.

Comment: Yes, thanks for comment, - i'm aware of those kind of things, and everything is fine at that part. I got license for my kind of "small lotteries". I just need to handle the virtual money safe:)